# Populate Ref of FaunaDB Collection

Tags: faunadb

I would like to populate or lookup of ref (Stored id of other collection in record) How I can populate Ref.
For Example I have 100000 records on user collection/table like bellow.

```
[{
  "firstName" : "Rajesh",
  "lastName" : "Gauswami"
  "companyId" : Ref(Collection("company"), "318686180733354176")
},
{
  "firstName" : "Vijay",
  "lastName" : "Gauswami"
  "companyId" : Ref(Collection("company"), "318686180733354177")

}]
```

Now I would like to know How I can populate company data also with user with Paging.

Comment: Can you include the query that you are currently using to fetch the example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Query composition](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/build/fql/composition) topic in the documentation should be helpful, especially the section titled "[Use Let to gather intermediate results](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/build/fql/composition#let)".